# Show li dynamically on hover using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

On hover of "category_name" class I want to show particular products for particular category.

For example for round neck tshirt it should show round neck - half sleeve, for v neck tshirt - v neck - plain half sleeve , for collar/polo t shirt - single line tipping, but when hover on round neck t-shirt it is showing all the products.

When I hover on round it should show li with id as product_183.

How to resolve this?

Below is my code:

```
<li class="navTab">
    <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=143_154" class="category_name">Round neck T-shirt (1)</a>
    <ul class="tabInner">
        <li id="product_183">
        <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=183" ><img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/roundneck-270x300.jpg" alt="Round Neck - Half Sleeve" title="Round Neck - Half Sleeve" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=183">Round Neck - Half Sleeve</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="navTab">
    <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=143_155" class="category_name">V- neck T-shirt (1)</a>
    <ul class="tabInner">
        <li id="product_184">
            <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=184" ><img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/singlelinetipping-270x300.jpg" alt="V Neck - Plain Half Sleeve" title="V Neck - Plain Half Sleeve" class="img-responsive" /></a>
            <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=184">V Neck - Plain Half Sleeve</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="navTab">
    <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=143_156" class="category_name">Collar/Polo T-shirt (1)</a>
    <ul class="tabInner">
    <li id="product_185">
    <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=185" ><img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/singlelinetipping-270x300.jpg" alt="Single Line Tipping" title="Single Line Tipping" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=185">Single Line Tipping</a>
    </li>
    <!-- <li><a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=143">More...</li> -->
    </ul>
</li>
```

Juqery code,

```
$(".category_name").hover(function(){
  //alert("coming");
  $('#product_183').show();
  $('#product_184').hide();
  // alert(product_id);
});
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Using css psudo class ::hover could be a better option. Make your 'popover' div hidden by default and `display:block` on hover. check out css psudo classes here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: On hover category_name class particular li should display not all li's but it is displaying all the li's.

Comment: The way your  JQuery code is.. it'll show ID conetent ```product_183``` & hide ID content  ```product_184``` whenever you hover over on the CLASS ```category_name```.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only show items of the hovered `li` you can try this:

```js
$(".navTab").hover(function(){
   $(this).find('ul').show();
   $(this).siblings().find('ul').hide();
});
```

```css
/**initially hide ul*/
.tabInner{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="navTab">
    <a href="#" class="category_name">Round neck T-shirt (1)</a>
    <ul class="tabInner">
        <li id="product_183">
        <a href="#" ><img src="" alt="Round Neck - Half Sleeve" title="Round Neck - Half Sleeve" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        <a href="#">Round Neck - Half Sleeve</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="navTab">
    <a href="#" class="category_name">V- neck T-shirt (1)</a>
    <ul class="tabInner">
        <li id="product_184">
            <a href="#" ><img src="" alt="V Neck - Plain Half Sleeve" title="V Neck - Plain Half Sleeve" class="img-responsive" /></a>
            <a href="#">V Neck - Plain Half Sleeve</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="navTab">
    <a href="#" class="category_name">Collar/Polo T-shirt (1)</a>
    <ul class="tabInner">
    <li id="product_185">
    <a href="#" ><img src="" alt="Single Line Tipping" title="Single Line Tipping" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    <a href="#">Single Line Tipping</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by replacing ur html and jquery by this

```js
    $("#Round").hover(function(){
        //alert("coming");
        $('#product_183').show();
        $('#product_184').hide();
        $('#product_185').hide();
        // alert(product_id);
    });
    $("#Vneck").hover(function(){
        //alert("coming");
        $('#product_183').hide();
        $('#product_184').show();
        $('#product_185').hide();
        // alert(product_id);
    });
    $("#Collar").hover(function(){
        //alert("coming");
        $('#product_183').hide();
        $('#product_184').hide();
        $('#product_185').show();
        // alert(product_id);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="navTab">
        <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=143_154" id="Round" class="category_name">Round neck T-shirt (1)</a>
        <ul class="tabInner">
            <li id="product_183" style="display: none">
            <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=183" ><img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/roundneck-270x300.jpg" alt="Round Neck - Half Sleeve" title="Round Neck - Half Sleeve" class="img-responsive" /></a>
            <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=183">Round Neck - Half Sleeve</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navTab">
        <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=143_155" id="Vneck" class="category_name">V- neck T-shirt (1)</a>
        <ul class="tabInner">
            <li id="product_184" style="display: none">
                <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=184" ><img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/singlelinetipping-270x300.jpg" alt="V Neck - Plain Half Sleeve" title="V Neck - Plain Half Sleeve" class="img-responsive" /></a>
                <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=184">V Neck - Plain Half Sleeve</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navTab">
        <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=143_156" id="Collar" class="category_name">Collar/Polo T-shirt (1)</a>
        <ul class="tabInner">
        <li id="product_185" style="display: none">
        <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=185" ><img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/singlelinetipping-270x300.jpg" alt="Single Line Tipping" title="Single Line Tipping" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=185">Single Line Tipping</a>
        </li>
        <!-- <li><a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=143">More...</li> -->
        </ul>
    </li>
```

let me know the result

Answer (score 0):

One more sample code...

**JQuery Code**

```
$(".category_name").hover(function(){

    var product_id = $(this).attr('product_id');
    console.log('product_id : '+product_id);

    if(product_id == 'product_183' ){
        $('#product_183').show();
        $('#product_184').hide();
        $('#product_185').hide();
    }

    if(product_id == 'product_184' ){
        $('#product_183').hide();
        $('#product_184').show();
        $('#product_185').hide();
    }

    if(product_id == 'product_185' ){
        $('#product_183').hide();
        $('#product_184').hide();
        $('#product_185').show();
    }
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<li class="navTab">
    <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=143_154" product_id='product_183' class="category_name">Round neck T-shirt (1)</a>
    <ul class="tabInner">
        <li id="product_183">
        <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=183" ><img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/roundneck-270x300.jpg" alt="Round Neck - Half Sleeve" title="Round Neck - Half Sleeve" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=183">Round Neck - Half Sleeve</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="navTab">
    <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=143_155" product_id='product_184' class="category_name">V- neck T-shirt (1)</a>
    <ul class="tabInner">
        <li id="product_184">
            <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=184" ><img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/singlelinetipping-270x300.jpg" alt="V Neck - Plain Half Sleeve" title="V Neck - Plain Half Sleeve" class="img-responsive" /></a>
            <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=184">V Neck - Plain Half Sleeve</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="navTab">
    <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=143_156" product_id='product_185' class="category_name">Collar/Polo T-shirt (1)</a>
    <ul class="tabInner">
    <li id="product_185">
    <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=185" ><img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/singlelinetipping-270x300.jpg" alt="Single Line Tipping" title="Single Line Tipping" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    <a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=&amp;product_id=185">Single Line Tipping</a>
    </li>
    <!-- <li><a href="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=143">More...</li> -->
    </ul>
</li>
```